# Integration tests - Dummy SSH Server not executing ssh commands correctly

Tags: java, spring, ssh, spring-batch

Spring batch project. There is a SshIService that accepts ssh commands and executes them. When the project runs in the Jenkins pipeline, it is able to create the ssh connections and my SshIService runs just fine.

While writing the Integration test for this SshIService service, I created a dummy SSH server which this service can talk to.

**Problem:** In the Integration test, when I am sending commands like `mkdir src/test/resources/Folder1 ; ls src/test/resources/Folder1 ;` the error is:

```
mkdir: ls: File exists
mkdir: src/test/resources/Folder1: File exists
mkdir: ;: File exists
```

The service is not considering these are separate commands and rather as a parameter for `mkdir` which is **WRONG**!
The problem is not specific to `mkdir`. Every time, more than 1 command separated by a semi-colon is executed in the Integration test, the issue arises.

I don't want to make changes to SshIService coz the entire project had been working using that logic. The issues seem to be in the SSH server created for the Integration test.

**Code for Integration test**

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SshIService.class, SshSftpConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SshSftpIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private SshIService SshIService;

    private SshServer dummy_sshd;

    @SneakyThrows
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        dummy_sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        dummy_sshd.setPort(9999);
        dummy_sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider());
        dummy_sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator((username, password, session) -> username.equals("someUserName") && password.equals("somePassword"));
        dummy_sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Collections.singletonList(new SftpSubsystemFactory()));
        dummy_sshd.setCommandFactory(new ProcessShellCommandFactory());
        dummy_sshd.start();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @AfterEach
    public void cleanup() {
        dummy_sshd.stop();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    public void sendCommandTest() {
        SshIService.sendCommand("mkdir src/test/resources/Folder1 ; ls src/test/resources/Folder1 ;");
        //Some assertions!
    }
}
```

**Code for SshIService**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class SshIService {
    private final SshSftpConfiguration sshSftpConfiguration;
    private final JSch sshTunnel;

    private Session sshSession;
    private ChannelSftp channelSftp;

    public SshIService(SshSftpConfiguration sshSftpConfiguration,
                          JSch sshTunnel) {
        this.sshSftpConfiguration = sshSftpConfiguration;
        this.sshTunnel = sshTunnel;
    }

    public String sendCommand(String command) throws IOException, JSchException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            connect();
            Channel channel = sshSession.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (!channel.isClosed()) {
                while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                    output.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                }
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            return cmdOut;
        } catch (IOException | JSchException | InterruptedException ioX) {
            log.error("Error: {}", ioX.getMessage());
            throw ioX;
        }
    }

    public String getHostAddress() throws UnknownHostException {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {
            if (sshSession == null || !sshSession.isConnected()) {
                sshSession = sshTunnel.getSession(sshSftpConfiguration.getUsername(), sshSftpConfiguration.getHost());
                sshSession.setPort(sshSftpConfiguration.getPort());
                sshSession.setPassword(sshSftpConfiguration.getPassword());
                sshSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            }

            if (sshSession != null && !sshSession.isConnected()) {
                sshSession.connect();
            }

            if (sshSession != null && channelSftp == null || !channelSftp.isConnected()) {
                channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) sshSession.openChannel("sftp");
                channelSftp.connect();
            }

        } catch (JSchException e) {
            log.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }

    public ChannelSftp getChannelSftp() {
        return channelSftp;
    }

    public void setChannelSftp(ChannelSftp channelSftp) {
        this.channelSftp = channelSftp;
    }

    public Session getSshSession() {
        return sshSession;
    }

    public void setSshSession(Session sshSession) {
        this.sshSession = sshSession;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Given that you have a `ChannelSftp` why don't you use its native methods (`mkDir()` , `ls()`, etc) instead of using an exec channel?

Comment: I can't change the code in SshIService class. Whatever has to be done, it has to be in Integration tests.

Comment: But you can use `SshIService.getChannelSftp().mkDir()` after calling `connect()` instead of calling `sendCommand()` to use the exec channel.

Comment: In the integration test, when I tried ```sshSftpService.getChannelSftp().mkdir("src/test/resources/Folder3/test");```, ```sshSftpService.getChannelSftp()``` is null.

Comment: You need to call `connect()` first - the field is set up there.

Comment: That works! BUT the goal here is to test the ```sendCommand()``` method. Coz sendCommand() should be able to take in any ssh command and execute it. Not just mkdir and ls.

Comment: What leads you to believe that a `Jsch` `ChannelExec` can handle multiple concatenated commands?

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't find any article saying that Jsch can not. In my project, when we are running the actual code in the Jenkins pipeline (not integration test), we are sending in multiple concatenated commands to the sendCommand() and it's working fine in there.

Comment: Right; but here you are not connecting to a general server over SSH; you are connecting to an Apache Mina SSH server with only an Sftp subsystem. That doesn't mean it will accept arbitrary OS/Shell commands.

Comment: Is there any alternate with the existing Apache Mina SSH server config OR any other SSH Server you can suggest, which I can use in the Integration test, that solves the purpose of testing the sendCommand() method?

Answer (score 2):

You are not connecting to a real server over SSH, you are connecting to an Apache Mina SSH server, with only an SFTP subsystem.

That doesn't mean it can accept arbitrary OS/shell commands.

https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/

> SSHD does not really aim at being a replacement for the SSH client or SSH server from Unix operating systems, but rather provides support for Java based applications requiring SSH support.

Comment: Is there any other server than the Apache Mina SSH server or the SftpSubsystemFactory, which can be used here, that would support concatenated commands? Or any other alternative to test the ```sendCommand()```

Answer (score 0):

try
SshIService.sendCommand("mkdir src/test/resources/Folder1 && ls src/test/resources/Folder1 ");

Comment: It ended up creating a folder with the name "&&" as well!

Comment: i think it is a syntax error try
 SshIService.sendCommand("mkdir src/test/resources/Folder1 ;" )
 SshIService.sendCommand("ls src/test/resources/Folder1 ;" )

Comment: The goal is to be to send multiple ssh commands (separated by ';') as one input parameter to the sendCommand() method and verify the result.

Comment: does not recognize ";" you can try with a pipe SshIService.sendCommand ("mkdir src / test / resources / Folder1 | ls src / test / resources / Folder1");

Comment: Still same issue. 

mkdir: src: File exists
mkdir: /: Is a directory
mkdir: /: Is a directory
mkdir: /: Is a directory
mkdir: src: File exists
mkdir: /: Is a directory
mkdir: test: File exists
mkdir: /: Is a directory
mkdir: resources: File exists
mkdir: /: Is a directory
mkdir: Folder1: File exists

Comment: you are sure to remove them before testing with " rm -r" ecc?